# Unable to Serialize into XML

Tags: c#-4.0, xml-serialization, expression-blend

I am trying to Serialize the content of some text into an XML file (performed when a user saves their selections), and then will later deserialize it (when the user chooses to display their saved selection).

I have been following the following [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) on serialization.

I have also tried to do this via LINQ to XML but was either getting namespace errors, or the tool returned no errors, but did not work (with the same problem as described below).

The problem I am having is that my code is not returning any errors, but the function is not working (I have a label control that allows me to see that the 'catch' is being returned). I am building the tool in Expression Blend, using C#.

Here is my SaveSelection.cs Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

namespace DYH
{
public class SaveSelections
{
    [XmlAttribute("Title")]
    public string Title
    { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Roof")]
    public string RoofSelection
    { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Cladding")]
    public string CladdingSelection
    { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MixedCladding")]
    public string MixedCladdingSelection
    { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FAJ")]
    public string FAJSelection
    { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("GarageDoor")]
    public string GarageDoorSelection
    { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FrontDoor")]
    public string FrontDoorSelection
    { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my C# code

```
// Save Selection Button
        private void Button_SaveSelection_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {   
            try
            {
                // Save selections into the SavedSelections.xml doc
                SaveSelections userselection = new SaveSelections();
                userselection.Title = TextBox_SaveSelection.Text;
                userselection.RoofSelection = Button_Roof_Select.Text;
                userselection.CladdingSelection = Button_Cladding_Select.Text;
                userselection.MixedCladdingSelection = Button_MixedCladding_Select.Text;
                userselection.FAJSelection = Button_FAJ_Select.Text;
                userselection.GarageDoorSelection = Button_GarageDoor_Select.Text;
                userselection.FrontDoorSelection = Button_FrontDoor_Select.Text;

                SerializeToXML(userselection);

//              XDocument xmlSaveSelections = XDocument.Load("../SavedSelections.xml");
//          
//              XElement newSelection = new XElement("Selection", //xmlSaveSelections.Element("Selections").Add(
//                      //new XElement("Selection",
//                      new XElement("Title", TextBox_SaveSelection.Text),
//                      new XElement("RoofSelection", Button_Roof_Select.Text),
//                      new XElement("CladdingSelection", Button_Cladding_Select.Text),
//                      new XElement("MixedCladdingSelection", Button_MixedCladding_Select.Text),
//                      new XElement("FAJSelection", Button_FAJ_Select.Text),
//                      new XElement("GarageDoorSelection", Button_GarageDoor_Select.Text),
//                      new XElement("FrontDoorSelection", Button_FrontDoor_Select.Text));
//              
////                xmlSaveSelections.Add(newSelection);
////                xmlSaveSelections.Save("../SavedSelections.xml");

                SelectionLabel.Text = "Your selection has been saved as " + "'" + TextBox_SaveSelection.Text + "'. We suggest you write down the name of your selection.";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                            throw ex;
                SelectionLabel.Text = "There was a problem saving your selection. Please try again shortly.";
            }
        }

        // Saves SaveSelection.cs to XML file SavedSelections.xml
        static public void SerializeToXML(SaveSelections selection)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveSelections));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"/SavedSelections.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, selection);
            textWriter.Close();
        }
```

I have left evidence of one of my previous attempts commented out so you can see a previous format I tried.

My issue is that when I try to use the tool, the SelectionLabel.Text returns "There was a problem saving your selection. Please try again shortly." so I know that the code is returning the catch and not executing the 'try'.

Any help??

**Edit 18/6/2012:** The below code was the code that worked as per correct answer to question.

```
public void Button_SaveSelection_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        string roofSelection = TextBox_SaveSelection.Text + "_RoofSelection";
        string claddingSelection = TextBox_SaveSelection.Text + "_CladdingSelection";
        string mixedCladdingSelection = TextBox_SaveSelection.Text + "_MixedCladdingSelection";
        string fajSelection = TextBox_SaveSelection.Text + "_FAJSelection";
        string garageDoorSelection = TextBox_SaveSelection.Text + "_GarageDoorSelection";
        string frontDoorSelection = TextBox_SaveSelection.Text + "_FrontDoorSelection";

        try
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                // Gives us 6Mb of storage space in IsoStore
                Int64 isoSpaceNeeded = 1048576 * 6;
                Int64 currentIsoSpace = store.AvailableFreeSpace;

                // If space needed is greater than (>) space available, increase space
                if (isoSpaceNeeded > currentIsoSpace)
                {
                    // If user accepts space increase
                    if (store.IncreaseQuotaTo(currentIsoSpace + isoSpaceNeeded))
                    {
                        IsolatedStorageFileStream file = store.CreateFile("SavedSelections.txt");
                        file.Close();

                        // Stream writer to populate information in
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(store.OpenFile("SavedSelections.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write)))
                        {
                            appSettings.Add(roofSelection, Button_Roof_Select.Text);
                            sw.WriteLine(roofSelection);
                            appSettings.Add(claddingSelection, Button_Cladding_Select.Text);
                            sw.WriteLine(claddingSelection);
                            appSettings.Add(mixedCladdingSelection, Button_MixedCladding_Select.Text);
                            sw.WriteLine(mixedCladdingSelection);
                            appSettings.Add(fajSelection, Button_FAJ_Select.Text);
                            sw.WriteLine(fajSelection);
                            appSettings.Add(garageDoorSelection, Button_GarageDoor_Select.Text);
                            sw.WriteLine(garageDoorSelection);
                            appSettings.Add(frontDoorSelection, Button_FrontDoor_Select.Text);
                            sw.WriteLine(frontDoorSelection);
                        }

                        SelectionLabel.Text = "Your selection has been saved as " + "'" + TextBox_SaveSelection.Text + "'. We suggest you write down the name of your selection.";
                    }
                }
            }

            SelectionLabel.Text = "Your selection has been saved as " + "'" + TextBox_SaveSelection.Text + "'. We suggest you write down the name of your selection.";
        }
        catch //(Exception ex)
        {
            //throw ex;
            SelectionLabel.Text = "There was a problem saving your selection. Please try again shortly.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should catch the exception and see what the message is to narrow down the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is because you're trying to a file, but that file did not come from a FileSaveDialog initiated by a user action.  You're running into a security feature of Silverlight where you're not allowed access to the local file system.  Instead, try writing to IsolatedStorage.  However, be aware that end users can completely (as well as selectively) disable application storage so you'll need to handle those exceptions as well.

[Here's a quick article on how to use IsolatedStorage.](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/16/tip-of-the-day-19-using-isolated-storage.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I will look into this and give this a go

Comment: I did this by follwing [link] (http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-use-isolated-storage-silverlight-358906/), again there is no runtime errors, but this time, my TextBlock notification does not work at all. Would you like me to update the code after your suggestion?

Comment: Sorry but how do I catch the exception?

Comment: Replace catch { ... } with catch (Exception ex) { ... } and then you can examine the exception that is being generated.  This should give you some clue as to why it's failing.

Comment: If the first line of the try block is not getting executed, then there's something wrong with how the event handler is being invoked.  Post your C# or XAML code that wires up the event handler.  Also, does the text "There was a problem ..." still appear?  If so, then I don't think your posted code matches what you're running.  (Anything after the throw statement won't be executed.)